# Counterexamples about the differentiability of several variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential

I've learned about differentiability of several variables.

If $f(x,y)$ is differentiable then we can use chain rule on it. But I suspect the converse of this proposition is not right. So, is there a function $f(x,y)$, such that the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0),\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$ exist, and for every functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ differentiable at $0$ satisfying $(x,y)(0)=(0,0)$, the chain rule $$\frac{df(x(t),y(t))}{dt}(0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)\frac{dx}{dt}(0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)\frac{dy}{dt}(0)$$ holds, but $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$? I'm curious about the counterexamples.

Comment: Your first and second sentences contradict each other: if you have continuous partial derivatives in a non-deleted neighborhood, then how is the function non-differentiable?

Comment: The first half of the question is flat-out wrong: a) there are functions that are differentiable, but whose partial derivatives aren't continuous; b) if partial derivatives exist in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ and they are continuous at $x_0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

Comment: @zkutch sorry I got it wrong. $xy\sin(1/(x^2+y^))$ is differentiable but its partial derivatives are not continuous at (0,0). I've edited the problem.

Comment: Are you asking this only for those $(x, y)(t)$ such that $f(x(t), y(t))$ is a differentiable function of $t$, or do you want $f(x(t), y(t))$ to be differentiable at $0$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are (and $(x,y)(0) = 0$)?

Comment: Andrews, can you please specify it in your post, rather than in comment? (Comments may be deleted or not read.)

Comment: Now that you have clarified your question, I find it very interesting. Please don't delete it. I hope somebody will be able to answer it precisely some day (positively or negatively: I have no intuition yet about it).

Answer (score 1):

[Chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) for functions from multiple variables generally doesn't work in case of only existence of corresponding partial derivatives.

Let's consider example
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}, &x^2+y^2>0 \\
0, &(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$$
For this function exists partial derivatives everywhere including point $(0,0)$, where $f'_x(0,0)=f'_y(0,0)=0$. By the way, exactly here partial derivatives are discontinuous.

If we consider simple functions $x(t)=y(t)=t$ and admit, that chain rule works, then we should have
$$\frac{df}{dt}=f'_xx'_t+f'_yy'_t=0$$
in point $t=0$.

But if we really substitute $x,y$ in $f$, then we obtain
$$f(x(t),y(t))=\frac{t^2\cdot t}{t^2+t^2}=\frac{1}{2}t$$
which gives derivative everywhere $\frac{1}{2}$ i.e. in point $t=0$ also.

**Addition**.
I explained partly in comment below, why I hope that brought answer is useful. And I, also, am adding following example:

Let's consider
$$g(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{t}, & t\ne 0 \\
0, & t=0
\end{cases}$$
and
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}, &x^2+y^2>0 \\
0, &(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$$
Obviously both are not differentiable in $0$ and $(0,0)$, but composition $g(f(x,y))=x^2+y^2$ is differentiable and partial derivative for $g\circ f$ can be obtained by chain rule - here it works.

Perhaps this does not exactly answer the horror that the question has become, but both of my examples, I hope, serve the main thing that, in my opinion, the querent wanted - to understand the chain rule.

Comment: This answer does not adress the question.

Comment: @Anne Bauval. My answer was made when in question was sentence "And if it is differentiable then we can use chain rule on it" and I show, that we cannot use "pure" existence of partial derivatives. you forced the author to change the text so many times that this part was simply lost, and now my answer of course seems irrelevant, while it clarified a certain detail in the former question. (continuing)

Comment: If the author had not discarded this thread of the question, then my answer would have been clearer to all those who, without understanding (or not being able to understand) the history of the issue, gave me a minus. When editing a question, you should not remove from it those threads of the topic that make the answers already given incomprehensible. It is better to delete the entire question and invite the author to ask a new one. I’m currently at a lecture, but if I find time, I’ll give an answer to the last variant also.

Comment: I forced the author to nothing, and did not remove anything. I only asked for clarification, and added a small precision to his own unique edit following my advice. But from the very beginning, and at the time this answer was posted, the question (after the remark "And if it is differentiable then we can use chain rule on it") was: "But **is there functions of several variables that can use chain rule but is not differentiable at a point?**".

Comment: At the moment, this answer adresses neither the first paragraph which was removed (which dealt with the relationship between continuity of the partial differentials and differentiability, but asked no question), nor the remaining one which was only clarified, not fundamentally changed. This might explain the minus (unique and not from me). I will be glad to upvote when the question is answered.

Comment: Guy, don't need to quarrel. It mainly was my fault because I didn't make the question clear. Should I delete the question and make a new one?

Comment: If you look at the question initially, it even consisted of generally contradictory proposals. This gives me reason to think that the person asking the question is just beginning to understand it and needs help even in how to pose the question. The ability to ask the right questions, from my point of view, leads to understanding the subject. But this is where it’s important not to overdo it with help. We must not narrow the question, but rather expand it, and, most importantly, the person himself should follow this path. Narrowing questions sometimes come down to completely unimportant points.

Comment: Let's take a look at what the question has become - where did the desire to consider internal functions that depend on only one variable come from? Isn't it from my answer? Then this is not the path that leads to understanding the chain rule. If we pose the question in general terms, then internal functions must depend on at least two variables. My answer gives a vision of the chain rule that is not usually found in textbooks, which is why I think it is useful.

Comment: @Anne Bauval. I may have offended you by using the word "force", I should have explained my view first, and I’m sorry for that, but if I could explain now what I didn’t like about your questions, and you forgave me, then everything is fine.

Comment: @Andrews. Do not delete, please, this question, if possible, now it is good lesson.

Answer (score 1):

*"If $f(x,y)$
is differentiable then we can use chain rule on it. But I suspect the converse of this proposition is not right"*: surprisingly, your guess is wrong, i.e. the converse *is* right. More formally:

**Theorem**. Let $f(x,y)$ be a function, and $a,b\in\Bbb R$. If, for every differentiable functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ satisfying $x(0)=y(0)=0$,
$$\frac{df(x(t),y(t))}{dt}(0)=ax'(0)+by'(0)$$
holds, then $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ (and of course, $df_{(0,0)}(h,k)=ah+bk$).

**Proof** (by contraposition). Assume
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=a,\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=b,$$
but $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, i.e.
$\frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-ah-bk}{\|(h,k)\|}\not\to0$ as $(h,k)\to(0,0)$, and let us construct a pair $(x,y)$ of differentiable functions such that $x(0)=y(0)=0$ and
$\frac{f(x(t),y(t))-f(0,0)}t\not\to ax'(0)+by'(0)$ as $t\to0$.

Since $\frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-ah-bk}{\|(h,k)\|}\not\to0$ as $(h,k)\to(0,0)$, there exist an $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $x_n+iy_n=r_ne^{i\theta_n}\to0$ such that $$|f(x_n,y_n)-f(0,0)-ax_n-by_n|\ge\epsilon r_n.$$ Wlog (extracting a subsequence), we can even assume that the positive sequence $(r_n)$ is decreasing, and that the sequence $(\theta_n)$ in $[0,2\pi]$ converges monotonically to some $\theta_\infty$.

Then, there exists a differentiable and monotonic function $(0,\infty)\to[0,2\pi],r\mapsto\theta(r)$, such that $\theta(r_n)=\theta_n$ ($\forall n\in\Bbb N$). The pair of functions $(x,y):[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R^2$, defined by $x(r)+iy(r)=re^{i\theta(r)}$ ($\forall r>0$) and $x(0)=y(0)=0$, is then differentiable, including at $0$, with $x'(0)+iy'(0)=e^{i\theta_\infty}$.

However, $\frac{f(x(r),y(r))-f(0,0)}r\not\to a\cos\theta_\infty+b\sin\theta_\infty$ as $r\to0$, since $$\left|\frac{f(x(r_n),y(r_n))-f(0,0)}{r_n}-a\cos\theta_n+b\sin\theta_n\right|=\frac{|f(x_n,y_n)-f(0,0)-ax_n-by_n|}{r_n}\ge\epsilon.$$